# My registrar won't/can't change my WHOIS entry - can I do it myself?

Tags: whois, domain-registration

I bought my first .com domain today, having recently used a country-specific domain. My registrar had to create an account for me on their new billing system to enable the transaction as part of the process and I didn't get a chance to review the contact details. Turns out, my personal mobile number is now in the WHOIS database and my registrar says they have no capability to change the entry.

Is there any way I can go about getting it changed myself?

Comment: I forgot to mention, my details were copied/moved from their old billing system.

Comment: That should have nothing to do with updating whois data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm curious who this mystery registrar is and whether they are a reseller for a larger organization.  ICANN's rules state that WHOIS information needs to be accurate for the contacts listed, and the registrar should provide you with a way to update that information on your own.  If they are a reseller for a larger registrar (reselling for OpenSRS, for example), you can complain to the actual registrar and they may allow you to move to another reseller if the one you're working with isn't competent.  Otherwise, transfer your domain to a more reputable registrar that has tools that work properly.

Comment: It's a reasonably big, Irish registrar. They've been in operation for quite a while.
The information is _accurate_, it's just a bit too accurate for my liking - I need a business phone number in there...

Comment: Your best bet in that case might be to contact them by phone and complain loudly and suggest they make the WHOIS data able to be managed through the website so they don't have to waste time and dollars listening to an otherwise happy and loyal customer complain about something they should be doing anyway.  Unfortunately I've found that many ccTLD-specific registrars have policies that defy logic.

Comment: http://www.icann.org/en/registrars/ra-agreement-21may09-en.htm - section 3.2.2 to the rescue! Quoting this to them caused an immediate change of heart.